# How to open a browser in Capybara and Selenium

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

I'm very new to Capybara and have also never used Selenium before. I'm doing a ruby on rails project on MacOSX and for whatever reason, a browser window never opens when I run my test. 
My stack is: Capybara, Selenium, Rspec, Ruby on Rails.
My test is as follows:

```
describe 'Downloads', js: true do

context ' compress zip and download file' do
  before do
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
    session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
    session.visit '/users/sign_in'
    find('#tab_signin').click
    within("#new_user") do
      fill_in 'user_login', :with => 'admin@local.host'
      fill_in 'user_password', :with => 'password'
    end
    click_button 'Sign in'
end

it 'downloads the project and navigates to downloads page' do
  visit 'some/path'
  within '.create-download' do
    find(:select).find("option[value='zip']").select_option
  end
  sleep 3
  page.should have_css('#download-modal.in')
end
```

end
end

I've also tried to change stuff in my features/support/env.rb to be this:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :profile => profile)
end
```

**Update**

Not only is the browser not opening, but the test is failing with the following output:

```
Failure/Error: visit '/users/sign_in'
 ArgumentError:
   unknown option: {:resynchronize=>true}
```

Comment: move `features/support/env.rb` content in `spec/spec_helper.rb`

Comment: possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030455/launching-browser-with-capybara

Comment: Are your tests failing or just not opening a browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after a lot of work I finally figured it out. Thanks to @RAJ for the suggestion of where to put that config info. The feature/support/env.rb is for cucumber and I'm using rspec.

Most of the articles I read about selenium and capybara told me to use the `js: true` option at the start of the block, but that didn't work. Once I changed that to `feature: true` it worked. My final solution looks like this:

```
describe 'Downloads', feature: true do

context 'compress zip and download file' do
before do

  visit '/users/sign_in'
  find("a[href$='signin']").click
  within("#new_user") do
    fill_in 'user_login', :with => 'admin@local.host'
    fill_in 'user_password', :with => 'password'
  end
  click_button 'Sign in'
end

it 'downloads the project and navigates to downloads page' do
  visit 'some/path'
  within '.create-download' do
    find(:select).find("option[value='zip']").select_option
  end
  sleep 3
  page.should have_css('#download-modal.in')
end
end
end
```

Then my spec_helper.rb looks like:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new( app, :profile => profile)
end
Capybara.default_wait_time = 10
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
Capybara.app_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
```

Another thing that I did and I wasn't aware before was install the Selenium IDE on Firefox. Since I'd never used Selenium before, I thought all I needed was the gem.

Comment: I was able to get it working with the `js: true` tag, although I'm not certain why it worked for me and not for your setup.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯   Your `spec_helper.rb` code did the trick for me though, so thank you!

Comment: @mycargus glad to hear!

Comment: After registering the driver, when I try to run any test I get this error. Any idea why that could be?

* ArgumentError: unknown option: {:profile=>#<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile:0x00000006984468 @model=nil, @native_events=true, @secure_ssl=false, @untrusted_issuer=true, @load_no_focus_lib=false, @additional_prefs={}, @extensions={}>}

Comment: @mickael sounds like you have an unknown option when you're instantiating your web driver. Though a comment is not the forum for this. You should probably ask a proper question if you cannot figure it out.